# Объединение таблиц по общей дате

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть две выборки из таблиц с общим столбцом date:

Первая:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(id) AS conversion,
    DATE(created_at) AS created_at
FROM
    sites_conversion
WHERE
    site_id = 2 AND partner_id = 70 AND is_unique = 0
GROUP BY
    DATE(created_at)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И вторая выборка:

```
SELECT
    SUM(conversion_pay) AS conversion_pay,
    SUM(orders_created) AS orders_created,
    SUM(orders_paid) AS orders_paid,
    SUM(earn_total) AS earn_total,
    SUM(revolution) AS revolution,
    DATE
FROM statistic
GROUP BY
    DATE
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно объединить эти две выборки по дате таким образом, чтобы учитывались даты из обеих столбцов. При этом даты из первой таблицы может не быть во второй и наоборот. Каким объединением это можно сделать? Перепробовал все.

Сейчас запрос выглядит так:

```
SELECT
    SUM(conversion_pay) AS conversion_pay,
    SUM(orders_created) AS orders_created,
    SUM(orders_paid) AS orders_paid,
    SUM(earn_total) AS earn_total,
    SUM(revolution) AS revolution,
    conversion, 
    DATE
FROM statistic
LEFT JOIN(
    SELECT
        COUNT(id) AS conversion,
        DATE(created_at) AS created_at
    FROM
        sites_conversion
    WHERE
        site_id = 2 AND partner_id = 70 AND is_unique = 0
    GROUP BY
        DATE(created_at)
    ) sites_conversion
ON
    created_at = DATE
GROUP BY
    conversion,
    DATE
```

И результат не учитывает даты, которые есть во внутреннем запросе (нет дат 2019-04-13 и 2019-04-14):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

То, что вы ищете называется "Full join", но он не поддерживается mysql.
Вы можете эмулировать его объединив два запроса с помощью UNION.
Вот пример с вашим запросом:

```
SELECT
    SUM(conversion_pay) AS conversion_pay,
    SUM(orders_created) AS orders_created,
    SUM(orders_paid) AS orders_paid,
    SUM(earn_total) AS earn_total,
    SUM(revolution) AS revolution,
    conversion, 
    DATE
FROM statistic
LEFT JOIN(
    SELECT
        COUNT(id) AS conversion,
        DATE(created_at) AS created_at
    FROM
        sites_conversion
    WHERE
        site_id = 2 AND partner_id = 70 AND is_unique = 0
    GROUP BY
        DATE(created_at)
    ) sites_conversion
ON
    created_at = DATE
GROUP BY
    conversion,
    DATE
UNION
SELECT
    SUM(conversion_pay) AS conversion_pay,
    SUM(orders_created) AS orders_created,
    SUM(orders_paid) AS orders_paid,
    SUM(earn_total) AS earn_total,
    SUM(revolution) AS revolution,
    conversion, 
    DATE
FROM statistic
RIGHT JOIN(
    SELECT
        COUNT(id) AS conversion,
        DATE(created_at) AS created_at
    FROM
        sites_conversion
    WHERE
        site_id = 2 AND partner_id = 70 AND is_unique = 0
    GROUP BY
        DATE(created_at)
    ) sites_conversion
ON
    created_at = DATE
GROUP BY
    conversion,
    DATE
```